# Looping through the keys collection

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to loop through a collection and display a list with item.date property. The idea is to click on that 'date' and be redirected to /item/${item.date} and to display all properties of that object.

1. I'm looping through keys in my collection which is expense1, expense2 etc...
2. creating that clickable link with the name of object prop - date

It doesn't display any list/links. I guess I'm missing something in my .map function because I know I can access all expenses in my  component.

Here's my code:

```
class ExpenseList extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        ExpenseList:
        <button onClick={this.props.loadSamples}>Load Sample Expenses</button>
        {Object
          .keys(this.props.expenses)
          .map(key =>
            <Link to={`/expense/${key.date}`} key={key} index={key}>
              {key.date}
            </Link>
          )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default ExpenseList;
```

My Routes:

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
        <Route path="/create" exact component={AddExpense} />
        <Route path="/expense/:expenseId" component={ExpenseDetails} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Comment: What is `Object` here?

Comment: @sashankaryal The builtin `Object` object?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Object.keys` function will, as the name suggests, return you each key defined on the object argument. But your code is treating each key as though it is the corresponding property value.

Instead, you need to use each `key` to access the corresponding property value as follows:

```
const expenses = this.props.expenses;

{Object
  .keys(expenses)
  .map(key =>
    <Link to={`/expense/${expenses[key].date}`} key={key} index={key}>
      {expenses[key].date}
    </Link>
  )
}
```

I assigned `this.props.expenses` to a different variable, because `this` in the `Array.map` function will refer to the callback function itself, not the component.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Now I see list and I'm redirected to /expense/some-date-1 when I click on the link. Does this <Link /> passes any props? how can I access props in my <ExpenseDetails /> component? I have updated  post with my Routes component

Comment: I'm trying to pass it via `details={expenses[key]}`

Comment: I'm not familiar with `BrowserRouter`, so I'm not sure. From the looks of your route though, you're expecting the expense ID. Are you using the date for the ID? Will the expense date always be unique in your application?

Comment: Hm. I might include id property later. I just need to display that specific expanse data in <ExpenseDetails /> component. Expecting to access it like `props.decription`, `props.amount` etc in <ExpenseDetails />